# Allow a subscriber to be an author and view only his post

Tags: customization, post-status

I have recently upgraded from 2.9.2 to 3.3.1.
Im using the edit flow plugin to assign different status to posts and allowing users to register and create a post with a specific status.
In the previous version, users could VIEW their posts as long as they were the author.
In the new version of WP, this is not the case - they see a 404 page.
I dont think this is an edit flow problem but a feature of the new WP.

How does one allow users(subscribers) to view ANY post status provided they are logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You must write a small plugin for the Hook `pre_get_posts`; an example:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fb_allow_draft' );

function fb_allow_draft( $query_obj ) {
    // only on admin screen use this filter
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    // change our query object to include any post status
    $query_obj->query_vars['post_status'] = 'any';
}
```

If you will specific this new loop for an rights object from an role, use the small question: `if ( ! current_user_can( 'read' ) ) return;`